# Convert mysql query from latin1 to utf8 using nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, encoding, latin1, node-mysql

I have a database in **latin1** and I want to convert its queries to 
 **utf-8**.

Example:

**response.write** returns this JSON:

```
{"questions":[{"question":"NaÃ§Ã£o","answer":"PaÃ­s"}]}
```

But I need it converted to utf8:

```
{"questions":[{"question":"Nação","answer":"País"}]}




conexao_bd.getConnection(function(err,con){
            if(err) return console.log("Erro na conexao. "+err);
            con.query("SELECT question, answer FROM "+tipo+" WHERE id IN "+c,function(err, rows){
                if(err) console.log("Erro na query questions: "+err);
                else{
                    for(var k =0;k<rows.length;k++)
                        perguntas.questions[k]={'question': rows[k].question,'answer':rows[k].answer};
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(perguntas));
                    con.release();
                    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
                    response.write(JSON.stringify(perguntas));
                    response.end();
                }
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-coding strings as posted by @bodokaiser is also a possibility, but it is not a clean system solution. The clean solution is to **tell the database to give you utf-8**. This can be done in two ways:

1. Set the connection charset using a query `set names utf8`.
2. Set the connection charset when you create connection. Don't know if this is possible in node.js. If not use the above option.

Comment: good suggestion I updated my answer. node-mysql seems to support charset as option

Answer (score 3):

You will need an extra module for converting different string encodings. [node-iconv](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv) seems to be one you are looking for! It is also mentained by the core developer of libuv/node so it should be quite sustainable. However think about updating the encoding on the database if possible as this may be the most lasting solution.

PS: With [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) it also should be possible to directly pipe the incoming data to a encoding stream (will probably not work but you get an idea):

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var iconv = require('iconv');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret'
});

connection.connect();
var query = connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution')
var encoder = new iconv.Iconv('latin1', 'utf-8');

// will encode result and pipe it to your terminal
query.pipe(encoder.pipe(process.stdout));
```

**EDIT**:
Thomas made a good suggestion about setting the charset in node-mysql if updating the database is not an options. This also seems possible see [here](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#connection-options) and should better than my hack. However if you are not using node-mysql this may be a workaround.